# Indexing precipitaiton data by month in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, indexing, time, size

I have an array of daily precipitation data over a geographic region that is structured long x lat x time. I want to be able to index this data by both month and year, and so used datevec to find the months/years of each timestep. All good! However, I'm having trouble creating the index because the number of dates in each month and each year are not equal.

Originally, I'd thought that I would create two indexes using a months loop and year loop to find the rows associated with each month/year in the datevec. That is, I wanted something like (row_loc x month) and ( year x row_loc), with NaN filling in places where there would be no data (i.e. the last several values in February, or the last values of non-leap years). However, matlab doesn't seem to like the fact that the number of rows for each month/year aren't the same.

```
dates = datevec;
months = 1:12;
years = 1979:2016;
ind_mo = NaN(1178,length(months));
ind_yr = NaN(366,length(years));
for m = months
    ind_mo(:,m) =  find(dates(:,2) == m);
end
for y = 1:length(years)
    ind_yr(:,y) =  find(dates(:,1) == y);
end
```

Eventually, I'd like to have a way to index the precipitation data by month and by year. If there's a way to do that through the structure I'm imagining...great! If there's another workaround that's good too, although I'd prefer not to have a separate index for each of the 12 months and 38 years since I think this will be cumbersome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are several ambiguous points.
1) What is exactly the format of the `datevec`? Could you provide its size? 
2) In the second loop it should be `ind_yr` instead of `ind_mo`.
3) You initialize the `ind_yr = NaN(366,length(years))`, which creates a NaN matrix of (366x38) size, but then, in the second loop you assign to entry `ind_mo(:,y)` with `y=1979:2016`, so the second index is from 1979 to 2016 when it should be from 1 to 38 (the year counter, not the actual year).
4) If you don't stick to matrices, you can try a cell array (38x12) and inside store vectors of variable sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the edits-I added them to my code above. The datevec is the length of the timeseries, with years, months, and days in each column assigned to each entry. I'll have to look into cell arrays and see if that will help with the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, now I got a better insight on what you are trying to do. In that case, if you are comfortable having NaNs as values, you can just use a multidimensional array: `precipitation = NaN(38,12,31);` and all the values of 26th year can be obtained as `precipitation(26,:,:)`, all the values of April through the years as `precipitation(:,4,:)` etc. You can of course reshape them into a vector, sum them etc. If that's sufficient for you I'll turn this into an answer.

Comment: Thanks...this is really close. The only thing missing is that I need to include two spatial dimensions, long and lat, because I'm calculating precipitation at multiple locations over a large geographic area. I know one thing I could do is turn my 3 dimensional array (long x lat x time) into a five dimensional array with months and years attached to each value, which is like what you suggested but just over more dimensions. If you know how to do that I'd definitely appreciate it.

Comment: Why use `datevec`? If you have a `datetime`, finding rows within a given date interval is trivial. Converting it to something else just makes that more difficult.

Comment: Thanks, datetime looks promising. With the datetime vector, do you know how to then create an index that would select all values from each month? When I try to index the prcp dataset using datetime I run into the same issue as above.